# LINQ to SQL entity and data-context classes: business object encapsulation

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

What are your favorite ways to encapsulate LINQ to SQL entity classes and data-context classes into business objects?

What have you found to work in a given situation?

Have you invented or taken to any specific patterns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a pattern which I think works best--In my case, at least.

I extend entity classes using partial classes. I use partial classes so the signature of the entity does not change (see the `DeleteOnSubmit` call in the `Delete` method).

I've cooked up a a small example. Here's an image of the database and LINQ to SQL class setup:

[image]

And here's the partial class in which I implement business logic:

```
/// <summary>
/// This class extends BusinessLogicDataContext.Products entity class
/// </summary>
public partial class Product
{
    /// <summary>
    /// New up a product by column: dbo.Products.ProductId in database
    /// </summary>
    public Product(Int32 id)
    {
        var dc = new BusinessLogicDataContext();

        // query database for the product
        var query = (
            from p in dc.Products 
            where p.ProductId == id 
            select p
        ).FirstOrDefault();

        // if database-entry does not exist in database, exit
        if (query == null) return;

        /* if product exists, populate self (this._ProductId and
           this._ProductName are both auto-generated private
           variables of the entity class which corresponds to the
           auto-generated public properties: ProductId and ProductName) */
        this._ProductId = query.ProductId;
        this._ProductName = query.ProductName;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Delete product
    /// </summary>
    public void Delete()
    {
        // if self is not poulated, exit
        if (this._ProductId == 0) return;

        var dc = new BusinessLogicDataContext();

        // delete entry in database
        dc.Products.DeleteOnSubmit(this);
        dc.SubmitChanges();

        // reset self (you could implement IDisposable here)
        this._ProductId = 0;
        this._ProductName = "";
    }
}
```

Using the implemented business logic:

```
// new up a product
var p = new Product(1); // p.ProductId: 1, p.ProductName: "A car"

// delete the product
p.Delete(); // p.ProductId: 0, p.ProductName: ""
```

Furthermore: LINQ to SQL entity classes are very open in nature. This means that the property corresponding to the *dbo.Products.ProductId* column implements both a getter and a setter--this field should not be changeable.

To my knowledge you can't override properties using partial classes, so what I usually do is implement a manager which narrows the object using an interface:

```
public interface IProduct
{
    Int32 ProductId { get; }

    void Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use the Repository pattern to encapsulate DataContexts.

[Repository Pattern](http://aspalliance.com/1672_Implementing_the_Repository_Pattern_with_LINQtoSQL.3)

I would like to find a better way to emit POCO objects from my data layer while using LINQ2SQL though.

Answer (score 2):

I just published a sample of how you can structure your application that uses Linq to Sql for storage, using IoC and T4-templates.

http://daniel.wertheim.se/2010/03/14/linq-to-sql-how-to-separate-the-entities-and-the-datacontext/

Answer (score 1):

Right now I'm trying to use LINQ to SQL entity classes as business objects, to pass them around between functions and services.

Of course, you should have **separate entity classes for database access**, so your database layout can change without changing the business objects!

I'd be most interested in a good solution for this, too!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the source code for the MVC Sample app that Rob Conery is putting together:

http://www.codeplex.com/mvcsamples/

He has a separate entity layer that maps to the LINQ to SQL classes.

Answer (score 0):

I did some experimentation using Entity Framework and Linq to Entities as a way to further separate my client code from the database, but I found it clumsy to use and was worried about the performance.

In my current project I use Linq to SQL as my data layer, but have separate classes where I implement all Linq queries. The classes return entities defined in my Linq to SQL context, but the queries are hidden in methods.

Answer (score 0):

I found the articles by [Ian Cooper on CodeBetter.com](http://codebetter.com/blogs/ian_cooper/archive/2008/07/01/architecting-linq-to-sql-part-10.aspx#184170) and [Stephen Walther](http://feeds.feedburner.com/StephenWalther) series invaluable in understanding the need to write the POCO entities first and then map them to the database rather than doing it the other way around (which is what I always used to do).

Answer (score 0):

I'm playing around with the idea to have a separate layer of OO model (better support for OO practices), but that use LINQ to SQL under the hood. The idea is to have an xml file that a custom tool will use to generate the code. 
Since LINQ to SQL entites are too cluttered for my preferences, I will auto-generate new classes to use as my entities and of course the DataContext will be completely hidden for the client code.
Do the short answer is: Create new entity classes but use the underlying LINQ to SQL entities and DataContext.